# How to choose between entering a Radius or a Diameter when creating a Circle

Tags: interface

When using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a Circle, you can specify the Radius of the circle in the tool panel. How can I choose between entering the Radius and entering the diameter?

Answer (score 2):

It's not posible to toggle the Radius field to Diameter. However, as the diameter is twice the radius there is a direct relationship between the two - so the Radius is the Diameter divided by 2. Also, Blender is capable of automatically interpreting mathematical formula when entering values.

Therefore, to create a circle of, say, 30 units in diameter, simply type `30/2` into the Radius field and Blender will automatically calculate 15 as the radius.